# How to create folders using user input for the name and number

Tags: shell-script, mkdir

The user will be asked 2 variables which will be the name of the folder and the number of folder they want to create. So if a user inputs sea and 3, the output should be: sea, sea2, sea3

```
read -p "Enter the name of the folder: " NAMEFOLDER
read -p "How many copies of this folder do you want?: " NUMFOLDER

i=0

until [ $i -gt $NUMFOLDER ]

do
mkdir $(($NAMEFOLDER))
((i=i+1))
done
```

then I am met with this problem

```
"mkdir: cannot create directory ‘0’: File exists"
```

I am stuck at this.

Comment: `$(( ))` is used for arithmetics. So when you do `$(($NAMEFOLDER))` you are trying to calculate something like `$((sea))`, which retuns `0`. So you always create directory 0. Drop the `$(( ))` to evaluate the variable only. Further comments: You never create a name that combines name+number, you may want to check if the number is a number and name does not contain illegal characters, you may want to check if a directory is already existing (all 3 optional), folders are commonly referred as directories in UNIX & Co. Maybe also explicitly name the shell you are using (POSIX `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`,)

Comment: I was able to fix it, thank you so much @FelixJN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, don't make your script read input at runtime. That is hard to use for your users since typos are inevitable and hard to fix, and also means the task cannot be easily repeated and automated. Instead, take the name and number as command line parameters.

Next, it is bad coding style to use CAPS for local shell variable names since by convention, the global environment variables are capitalized and this can lead to unexpected naming collisions and hard to debug issues.

Now, you real problem here is that you are using `$((foo))` which means "treat `foo` as a mathematical expression and return its result". For example:

```
$ echo $((4 + 3 ))
7
```

Of course, the entire script doesn't really make sense either since you cannot create multiple files or directories with the same name. Perhaps you meant to add a counter?

Maybe something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

folderName="$1"
folderNumber="$2"

for((i=1; i<=$folderNumber; i++)); do
  mkdir -p "$folderName"_$i
done
```

Which you execute like this:

```
foo.sh bar 4
```

And would result in:

```
$ ls
bar_1  bar_2  bar_3  bar_4
```

If you want the first directory created not to have a suffix, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

folderName="$1"
folderNumber="$2"

mkdir -p "$folderName"
for((i=2; i<=$folderNumber; i++)); do
  mkdir -p "$folderName"_$i
done
```

Which results in:

```
$ foo.sh bar 4
$ ls
bar  bar_2  bar_3  bar_4
```

Comment: thank you, that did the trick! I appreciate the detailed response, I will take this into practice and hopefully be better next time.